# What is the difference between the methods iterator and view?

Tags: scala, collections

```
scala> (1 to 10).iterator.map{_ * 2}.toList
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)

scala> (1 to 10).view.map{_ * 2}.force
res2: Seq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

Other than using next,hasNext, when should I choose iterator over view or view over iterator?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a huge difference between iterators and views. Iterators are use once only, compute on demand, while views are use multiple times, recompute each time, but only the elements needed. For instance:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3).map{x => println(x); x * 2}
1
2
3
list: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)

scala> list(2)
res14: Int = 6

scala> list(2)
res15: Int = 6

scala> val view = List(1,2,3).view.map{x => println(x); x * 2}
view: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)

scala> view(2)
3
res12: Int = 6

scala> view(2)
3
res13: Int = 6

scala> val iterator = List(1,2,3).iterator.map{x => println(x); x * 2}
iterator: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> iterator.drop(2).next
1
2
3
res16: Int = 6

scala> iterator.drop(2).next
[Iterator.next] (Iterator.scala:29)
(access lastException for the full trace)
```

Answer (score 23):

`view` produces a lazy collection/stream. It's main charm is that it won't try and build the whole collection. This could prevent a OutOfMemoryError or improve performance when you only need the first few items in the collection. `iterator` makes no such guarantee.

One more thing. At least on `Range`, `view` returns a `SeqView`, which is a sub-type of `Seq`, so you can go back or start again from the beginning and do all that fun sequency stuff.

I guess the difference between an iterator and a view is a matter of in-front and behind. Iterators are expected to release what has been seen. Once `next` has been called, the previous is, hopefully, let go. Views are the converse. They promise to not acquire what has not been requested. If you have a view of all prime numbers, an infinite set, it has only acquired those primes you've asked for. It you wanted the 100th, 101 shouldn't be taking up memory yet.

Comment: See Iterator#map, it creates a new iterator that lazily evaluates the function passed to map for each 'next'. So it seems to act exactly like a view

Comment: @Ittay: True, but that's not in the contract. Iteractor promises 'next method which returns the next element and discards it from the iterator.' Whereas IterableView promises be 'non-strict'.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) talks about when to use views.

> In summary, views are a powerful tool to reconcile concerns of
>   efficiency with concerns of modularity. But in order not to be
>   entangled in aspects of delayed evaluation, you should restrict views
>   to two scenarios. Either you apply views in purely functional code
>   where collection transformations do not have side effects. Or you
>   apply them over mutable collections where all modifications are done
>   explicitly. What's best avoided is a mixture of views and operations
>   that create new collections while also having side effects.